# Do we allow duplicates as a way to draw attention to questions that don't get satisfactory answers?

Tags: discussion, help-center

According to [the current version of the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

> duplicate - the fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

Are we allowing people to re-ask the same questions, just because they didn't get a satisfactory answer before? Note that this assumes that it is indeed the same question, not merely a similar looking one.

Comment: It says "to explain how it is different". I think that's the important part. Questions may look superficially similar, but have a different answer.

Comment: @CodyGray: But what if it is the exact same question? From the same person. Who stated in a comment that they wanted to get an answer and weren't satisfied with the previous ones. Also, it says "or", not "and".

Comment: No, I don't think that's permitted. That's why we use the phrasing "exact duplicate". I don't think that's what the wording is suggesting either (although perhaps it could be rephrased). I think it is saying that asking a brand new question is an alternative to editing the closed one. It's still required that you explain how it's different than the other duplicate.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think in that case, users should create bounties.

Comment: A question that crosses a lexical threshold to the content of an earlier question does not necessarily make it a duplicate, but many times this appears to be the sole criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, I think the wording can definitely be improved.

Let's split the last sentence into 2 parts and examine each separately

### Part I

> If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different

The wording seems to imply that if the answers of the linked question don't solve the user's problem, that means the question must necessarily be different. Not necessarily. What if the answers are just bad or not very explanatory (from the user's POV), among other possibilities?

### Part II

> If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

I find this confusing actually. Why is the user advised to ask a new question instead of editing his (closed as dupe) question to show how it's not a duplicate? Won't that new question be closed as duplicate all over again?

### Also

> ... and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully ...

The transition from a singular to a plural sounds out of place. I know what it's trying to say, but the way it's worded just sounds weird.

### Reformulation

Something that goes roughly like this (I know it's overly verbose but it's a rough draft)

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If you think that your question is different from the linked question, please edit your question to explain how it is different. If you have the same question as the linked question and you don't think that the answers there solve your problem, please do so and so...

I dropped the "ask a new question" part because I don't understand what it's for.

Comment: The "ask a new question" part is there for people who came via Google. Maybe there should be two versions of this message, one from the OP and one for googlers?

Comment: You mean that part is not directed to the OP? Now *that*'s confusing.

Comment: The main quest of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of questions and answers, and majority of views is expected to come via Google. Anonymous googlers get an auto-redirect, but logged on users don't.

Comment: I don't mean "directed" in the sense of redirect. I mean, the message about "asking a new question" is not meant for the OP? That part of the close message very much look like specific instructions to the OP to do something about the closed/on-hold question.